# Max Time for computation on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to develop a Time Table Generator using either Python or Java on Google App Engine. This app will take at least 4 to 5 minutes to compute the result in the end when all the data has been entered.

My doubt is how to run a complex process which takes long time to process on Google App Engine since the max time allowed for a process is 60 seconds and also whether the task queues will be of any help here?

Also is there any other free cloud host which I can use for this purpose?

Comment: you probably want this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deferred as it has a 10 minute time out. some cursory research on your behalf would have shown this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen this but my doubt is should my program be written differently if I have to use task queues. I don't really know about this task queues concept so please help me out.

Comment: You just throw a function at a task and it runs till completion, max 10 minutes. the deferred library makes it very easy to use. Just remember that when you check for the "results" of that task you don't wait for the task to complete. Rather the task itself updates a status which is then checked by a handler you create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the Google App Engine (GAE) you have only a 10 minute timeout if you are using a [Task Queue](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/). You can also using [Backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/backends) (as explained in the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#Billing_Quotas_and_Limits): *Backends are exempt from the 60-second deadline for user requests and the 10-minute deadline for tasks, and run indefinitely.*).

Maybe the [Amazon Web Services (Elastic Beanstalk)](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) are a better place for your needs :) .