# How to increase time of app engine request handler as it abort each request in 60 sec?

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine

I have an application deployed on GAE having endpoints. Each endpoint make a connection with database , get data and close connection and return data. Normally everything works fine but when there is hike in requests it starts taking more than 60 sec and requests get aborted. Due to this it does not close database connection and there mysql got 1000+ connections and then each requests starts aborting and it shows deadline exceeded error.  Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the "get data" portion with a `try... finally...` statement and move the "close connection" portion in the `finally` section. Then start an "about to exceed deadline" timer before "get data" (something like say 45 seconds) and raise an exception if the timer expires, allowing you to close the connection in the `finally` portion, which should take care of the orphan open connections (but would not prevent errors in those requests).

If your application tolerates it you could also look into using task queues which have a 10 min deadline, which could help reducing/eliminating the errors in the requests as well.

You can also find some general advice for addressing deadline exceeded errors here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors, donno if applicable to your app.

EDIT: actually the suggestion in the first paragraph above doesn't work on GAE as the Python sandbox doesn't allow installing a custom signal handler:

```
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timer_expired)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signal'
```

After seeing your code a somehow equivalent solution would be to replace your `cursor.fetchall()` with a loop of `cursor.fetchone()` or `cursor.fetchmany()` to split your operation in smaller pieces:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html. You'd get a start timestamp (with `time.time()` for example) when entering your request handler. Then inside the loop you'd get another timestamp to measure the time elapsed so far since the start timestamp and you'd break out of the loop and close the DB connection when deadline expiration nears. Again, this won't help with actually replying successfully to the requests if it takes so much time to prepare the replies.

Comment: how can I use timer , can you please explain ? Here is my code to connect  database from python  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30913255/how-to-solve-process-terminated-because-the-request-deadline-was-exceeded-err

Comment: I had in mind using `signal.SIGALRM` for the timer, but it doesn't work as the GAE python sandbox doesn't allow overriding the signal handler: http://w3facility.org/question/does-google-app-engine-support-pythons-signal-module/. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution to close connections when deadlines are exceeded:

[Dealing with DeadlineExceededErrors](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors?hl=en)

This way you won't have any open connections hanging there forever.

Comment: i did not get any solution from above link :(

Comment: Catch DeadlineExceededError exception and close database connection before hard deadline exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Think about the design of your application -

1.Use the deadline exception handling - Design smells

> > Because there will be situation(s) where db operation takes more than 60 seconds , If its a simple query then its well and good , but reconsider the design of the application . **User Expierence**  is going to be hurt.

2.Lets change the design to use the endpoints-

> > https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/ 
> >     `The way to go ,future proof.`

3.Using Back-end or Task-queues as descibed in this post

> > [Max Time for computation on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998591/max-time-for-computation-on-google-app-engine)

Answer (score -1):

You can set the Timeouts
interactive_timeout
and / or
wait_timeout
based on connection Type they use one of them

Comment: These settings won't affect App Engine. It has a 60 sec. deadline for HTTP requests if using automatic scaling.

Comment: You can set this Values global for the Database or only local per session